# How to add additional context to a django form widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

the basic Django `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget allows for a `label` and `value` to be passed through to the template.  I want to add 2 additional fields from a model but I cannot work out how, although I believe it is through subclassing `get_context`

I have this model and I would like to include the `icon` and `description` in the widget

```
class AddOnItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = 'AddOn Title',
        max_length = 50
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = 'Description',
        max_length = 255
    )
    icon = models.FileField(upload_to="addon_icons/", blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Within my form I've specified this widget

```
class JobPostWizardForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = [
            ...,
            'addons'
            ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...

        self.fields['addons'].widget = AddOnCheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['addons'].queryset = AddOnItem.objects.filter(active=True)
```

And I've subclassed the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget as

```
class AddOnCheckboxSelectMultiple(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    template_name = 'jobboard/widgets/addon_checkbox_select.html'
    option_template_name = 'jobboard/widgets/addon_checkbox_option.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value,attrs)
        return context
```

Obviously this doesn't do anything at the moment but I want to add something like

```
context['icon'] = obj.icon
```

but I cannot work out how to do this.  That is, I do not follow how Django widgets are getting the object.

I would greatly appreciate any help available - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best solution, but it works.

I override `create_option` like so:

```python
def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):
    ctx = super().create_option(name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=subindex, attrs=attrs)
    obj = AddOnItem.objects.get(id=int(value))
    ctx['icon'] = obj.icon
    ctx['description'] = obj.description
    ctx['price'] = obj.price

    return ctx
```

I can then get these attributes with `{{ widget.field_name }}` within the template.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `MultiWidget`, similarly to @HenryM's answer, one can subclass `get_context` method and assign values like so:

```
def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
    context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
    context["some_field"] = "some_value"
    return context
```

Which in template can be accessed by `{{ some_field }}`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `ModelForm` that has a `ForeignKey` (`ModelChoiceField`) you can set additional context in custom widget like so:

```
class CustomRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    option_template_name = "widgets/test.html"

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        for option in context['widget']['optgroups']:
            _, opts, _ = option
            for opt in opts:
                opt['other_attributes'] = opt['value'].instance.other_attributes
        return context
```

In this example my model has an attribute `other_attributes` that I wanted to access in my widget.

Then in my `option_template`:

```
{{ widget.other_attributes }}
```

This saves another trip to the database to add more information from the model.